# postgres sql selecting by weekday including empty records in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

I have a query which is 90% there, I'm querying data on whats going on for each day of the week which works fine for data that is there but I'd also like data for those that aren't (I want the query to include zeros for days of the week that don't exist).

```
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at) AS number, COUNT(*) FROM "events" GROUP BY number
```

or for rails...

```
Event.select("EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at) AS number, COUNT(*)").group("number")
```

The result.

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | number | count |
+----+--------+-------+
|    | 0.0    | 16    | # day of the week Sunday
|    | 1.0    | 20    |
|    | 2.0    | 29    |
|    | 3.0    | 19    |
|    | 4.0    | 4     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

How can I expand this query to map all of the days of the week, even if there are no records? (to look like this).

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | number | count |
+----+--------+-------+
|    | 0.0    | 16    |
|    | 1.0    | 20    |
|    | 2.0    | 29    |
|    | 3.0    | 19    |
|    | 4.0    | 4     |
|    | 5.0    | 0     | # i want these zeros too!
|    | 6.0    | 0     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
events = Event.select("EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at) AS number, COUNT(*)").group("number")

counts = events.each_with_object({}) do |event, counts|
  counts[event.number.to_i] = event.count
end

weekdays = (0..6).map do |day|
  {
    number: day,
    count: counts[day] || 0
  }
end
```

It should give you an array of hashes for each day with the count for that day even if the count is zero. I can't fully test it because I don't have your DB table but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.